# Review a declined flag for plagiarism based on additional information

Tags: support, status-completed, declined-flags, plagiarism

I had [flagged this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14060804/2985643), posted on December 27, 2012, as "*in need of moderator intervention*" for plagiarism:

> *This answer is plagiarism. The poster's answer is copied with minor changes and without attribution from https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/why-character-array-is-better-than.html*

This is [the blog entry that I believe was plagiarized](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/why-character-array-is-better-than.html):

[image: Current blog entry]

My flag was declined because it was claimed that the SO answer preceded the blog on the external web site. However, I still believe the SO answer was plagiarized. I had flagged it because:

- The URL for the external blog included "**2012/03**", suggesting that it was posted in March 2012, whereas the SO answer was posted in December 2012.
- The first three comments of the blog were timestamped prior to the date of the SO answer.

Having "**2012/03**" in the URL is inconclusive in itself, but that URL coupled with the timestamp of the first comment on the blog (March 26, 2012 10:13 PM) strongly supports the view that the blog existed in March 2012.

Unfortunately I had not noticed something spotted by the SO reviewer: the date of the blog entry was "**WEDNESDAY, MARCH 15, 2017**" (as shown in the screen shot above), and that was why my flag was declined:

> *It's the other way around. The blogspot post was explicitly copied from SO and is dated more than 4 years after this answer.*

However, for that to be true 21 of the comments for the blog had to have been posted before the blog itself, which makes no sense. Those comment timestamps strongly suggest that only the date of the blog article had been updated, and checking [an archive of the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120530192724/http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/why-character-array-is-better-than.html#more) shows this to be the case:

[image: Wayback Machine blog entry]

Note that the date for that blog was originally "**THURSDAY, MARCH 15, 2012**", and not "**WEDNESDAY, MARCH 15, 2017**" as is currently displayed.

I am guessing that the web site bumped the date on the article (by exactly five years) to make it still appear relevant. Regardless, the blog definitely existed over nine months prior to the SO answer which provided no attribution.

Given the information from the Wayback Machine archive, the SO answer was clearly plagiarized, so could a moderator please revisit this issue? I would just let the issue die except that this case is particularly galling because:

- The text of the answer includes the use of the first person: "*I also suggest working with hashed or encrypted password...*". Stealing someone else's work is bad enough, but pretending to be someone else is doubly offensive.
- The plagiarized text was subtly changed. For example, the variable `charPassword` was renamed as `charPwd`. This obviously isn't a case of simply forgetting to provide attribution.
- The plagiarized answer received 136 upvotes. Plagiarsm should not be rewarded.

Comment: The [1st revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14060804/revisions) even has the original code, only in the 2nd revision the code-snippet was *improved* ... I agree this flag should not have been declined, it should have been Larsoned ...

Comment: Easy for a mod to miss all these details without your sleuthing. Good catch.

Comment: I didn't handle this flag, but *internal screaming that reviewing plagiarism is hard*

Comment: That's an old answer. IIUC removing it now won't take away all of the rewards it got along the years. Still, it shouldn't be allowed to accumulate more.

Comment: Also, did you know that there are entire networks of blogs that copy from one another so you can't even trace the original source for some copied content? What would you do if you were in our shoes? (I've been able to do just that in maybe one or two out of a small handful of these cases. And I spent maybe 20 minutes on it.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, crud. I handled that flag. In light of your very thorough explanation and a second look on my part, I clearly got that one wrong. I saw the date on the page and assumed this was the typical situation—people stealing content from SO—rather than plagiarism *on* SO, which, thankfully, is less common. Assumptions are bad, and I missed the clues in the URL and comments. My apologies.

The plagiarized post has been deleted.

Thanks for flagging this and being so thorough in your explanation here. Again, I’m sorry I declined your flag incorrectly.

Comment: Boi I pride myself as one of the most careful and thorough plagiarism reviewers on the team and I'm pretty sure even I would have had a double-take at this. So don't sweat it.

Comment: Thanks, @BoltClock. I’m just a little bummed one got by me, even if it was a little weird.